# Ion Auth and Bootstrap Modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, authentication, controller, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

I want to integrate Ion Auth into my bootstrap login which is a modal, I'm using Code Igniter. How do I call Ion Auth's Login method when the login button is clicked? If I use redirect won't it reload the page and remove the modal?

Can I call the controller with an onclick? or put the login() from the controller and make it as javascript? haha

Really need help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a new controller method to login via Ajax

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ion Auth with CodeIgniter calling login functions form every controller. Ex:

```
<?php

class Files extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('files'); //to load your model

        if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            redirect("auth/login", 'refresh');  //if you are not logged go to controller auth, function login to show the login form
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        //do something - you are already logged
    }

    ///here your functions in controller

}
```

..hope this can help you.

Comment: ...sorry, now I see that you have asked for a solution which can work with bootstrap modal.